# Recognizing ASP.NET MVC security trimming request in AuthorizeAttribute override

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc, security-trimming

I have a controller with a custom Authroize attribute on a method:

```
   class ItemsController
       [MyAuthorize]
       ActionResult MyMethod()
```

I also use Kendo ASP.NET MVC to create a menu. Kendo provide a great feature with Security trimming where if I try to add a menu item to `MyMethod`, as Kendo is building the menu, it will check if the current user will have access to the `MyMethod` action.  I don't know how this works or is done.

The issue I am running into is that my code in `MyAuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore()` logs when a user makes a request and is not authenticated or authorized to view the requested page.  This works great *except* when the user doesn't have access to one of the pages in the menu.  Somehow Kendo triggers the `MyAuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore()` code for the action/controller that the menu item points to.  That's all fine except I don't want to log that.  The user didn't make a request to the action/controller, it is just an internal check.

So my question is, is there a way for me to determine if the call to `MyAuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore()` is a security trimming request or an actual page request?

Comment: You should have access to the `Request` in the Attribute.  So depending on if you can tell the different between requests (take a look at the ajax call in chrome dev tools) then you can certainly put the same logic in the `MyAuthorize` attribute.  However, I wouldn't even make it do unnecessary calls, you can use reflection to return all the valid methods available to the current user per controller pretty easily.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, yes, that is what I am trying to figure out... how to differentiate between a request and a method call in this case.  I suspect that the calling method in the security trimming case passes its own HttpContext.  But I don't know that.